# How to Copy Text from pop up/Dialogue box by imacros and paste it on field

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

I want to copy and paste text from popup window by macros.i have captured the image

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqAPa.jpg) showing the text that I need to copy.

This is the code that I am using to paste.

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:OnlineForm ATTR=ID:passport_no CONTENT={{!VAR2}}`

Comment: You can use EVAL and JS to remove the unnecessary text.

Comment: i need to copy the marked text in the image by imacros

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are able to extract the text mentioned in the image?, if Yes then try the below tag, I hope it will work, if it doesn't then use JS.

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x;var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\";s=s.split(/:/);s=s[1].split(/./);s=s[0];if (s != null){x=s;}")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:OnlineForm ATTR=ID:passport_no CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

Using the JavaScript

```
var s=iimGetLastExtract();
s=s.split(/:/); 
s=s[1].split(/./);
s=s[0] //Here 's' will contain A8BA1A
iimSet ("s",s);
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:OnlineForm ATTR=ID:passport_no CONTENT="+{{s}});
```

Comment: the main fact is will it could spilt selected text from pop up windows like the image?

Comment: both two item are not working,, is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: it's not extract from image,, it from popup page in browser like image

Comment: What I meant is.. whether you are able to extract the text mentioned in the msg box?.. I provided the steps only after the extract.. What's the code to Extract the text.. do you have the TAG?

Comment: can you contact me on skype? my id is gs_sharwar..it is very urgent for me please help

Comment: Jagadeesh Karunakaran plz help me